# Delete row if found specific string Python

Tags: python, pandas

df:

```
Column1  Column2
1        Balneolaeota;
2        Caldiserica;
3        Calditrichaeota;
4        Candidatus Abawacabacteria;
5        candidatus Adlerbacteria;
```

I want to delete all rows that contain the string "Candidatus" and "candidatus" in the second column.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `str.contains`:

```py
df = df[~df['Column2'].str.contains('candidatus', case=False)]

Out[1]: 
   Column1          Column2
0        1     Balneolaeota
1        2      Caldiserica
2        3  Calditrichaeota
```

Comment: ```df = df.loc[~df['Column2'].str.contains('candidatus', case=False)]``` ;)